# Date Time conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting datetime as 1/2/2010 11:29:30 which I am displaying in a gridview.
 and I want to convert it to "Feb 1, 2010 at 11:29".

Please let me know how to convert it like this.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using asp.net with C#.

Comment: I tried to do it with
Text='<%# Eval("DatePosted","{0:M-dd-yyyy at HH:MM}") %>'>

but I want it like Feb 1, 2010 at 11:29 AM

Comment: Are you using a template or just displaying the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) method of `DateTime`, it is extremely useful in formating your dates. Here is a quick example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Date
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ((DateTime)Eval("DatePosted")).ToString("MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

For a reference on other formatting options, see [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Comment: When I posted my answer, SO didn't show any others. That and when you ask a question, wouldn't you be glad there's a bunch of different answers?

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion your answer did not add any value as you stated the same as the other answers but only 10 minutes later :) Well well, no problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

This format should do it:

```
"MMM d, yyyy a\\t hh:mm"
```

just call the `ToString` of the DateTime instance and pass that string as a format

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp headertext="CreationDate" :TemplateField>
   <itemtemplate>
    <asp id="Label1" runat="server"
 Label.Text='<%# Bind("DatePosted", "{0:M-dd-yyyy at HH:MM}") %>'>;
    </asp>
   </itemtemplate>
  </asp>
```