# Converting convert the datetime in dd/MMM/yyyy to string in dd/MM/yyyy format C#

Tags: c#

I have a input variable with DateTime datatype in "03-Jan-2010" format I want to convert that in to a String type of dd/MM/yyyy format.How can this be done using C#.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What aspect of this requirement are you having problems with?

Comment: You already have it, as you said... [ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There really are several answers out there on how to convert formatted date/time strings. I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date and time conversion in C# - DateTime.ParseExact() not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376231/date-and-time-conversion-in-c-sharp-datetime-parseexact-not-working-as-expec)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Time conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797828/date-time-conversion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”) returns dd.MM.yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273215/datetime-tostring-dd-mm-yyyy-returns-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Some people are saying its duplicate and some people are answering the question which I don't know how the understood as the its so unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
datetime.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

Remember, [`"/"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time formatting as *replace me current culture's or specified culture date separator*. If your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is already `/`, you can use it without escaping like;

```
datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or you can provide [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) which has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) as a second parameter to your `.ToString()` method (ex: [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) ) like;

```
datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ddd=  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Visit: http://forums.asp.net/t/1820419.aspx?How+to+convert+dd+mm+yyyy+format+date+into+yyyy+dd+mm+in+C+

Comment: This is not OP wants IMHO..

Answer (score -1):

Please try following demo you will get what you want

```
string myDate = "03-Jan-2010";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime.TryParseExact(myDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Console.Write("Formatted Date : {0}", formattedDate);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope it works for you...

Comment: Op said: _I have a variable with DateTime.._ That's why I don't think he/she needs to parsing stuff. And `"dd/MM/yyyy"` doesn't provide _exact_ representation with `/` separator because it has a special meaning in custom formatting.

Comment: Yes the input I get is in the DateTime format not as String.